# GWT - Changing CSS hover property

Tags: css, gwt, dynamic, themes

I'm a new user of GWT and I'm looking for some advice concerning "theme management".

I have to make a website that can handle theme changes. What I mean is that a user can make is own theme by filling a form, then the website will automatically and dynamically changes its color to display the new ones.

I thought using a CSS sheet for all the static properties and using some GWT lines (e.g. label.getElement.getStyle.setColor(...)) to change color. But I have many "hover" properties and I think creating many MouseOverHandler is not a good idea ...

Is there a way to edit CSS sheet dynamically or a magic trick to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options - the most straight forward (to me) is to make use of the existing CSS classes that GWT introduces. If you look at javadocs for any of the widgets GWT provides, you'll notice the `CSS Style Rules` section. For example, [`Button`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html):

```
.gwt-Button  
    the outer element
```

That means that every `Button` you add to the page has a `.gwt-Button` style applied to it. If you inject a CSS stylesheet with a rule that overrides this style:

```
.gwtButton {
    background: red;
}
```

All your buttons will turn red. You can inject stylesheets using [`StyleInjector`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/StyleInjector.html). Creating the stylesheet's content dynamically is up to you - but it's just text, it shouldn't be hard (but make sure the generated CSS rules are valid!).

To get you started, try hooking up this code to some button and see if clicking it triggers changing all the `Buttons` on the page red:

```
StyleInjector.inject(".gwt-Button { background: red; }");
```

If you have custom widgets that you want styled differently, just add an individual class to them (`.customWidgetWhatever`, like `Button` has `.gwt-Button`, etc.) that you will include in your custom stylesheet.

Make sure you understand how CSS works and what it can do for you. For example, if you want to style each button the same, you don't have to change each button's style individually, just use:

```
button {
    background: green;
}
```

And all the `<button>`s will turn green.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change themes without reloading the whole application is to assign a theme class to the `body` element.

You'd want to prepend each CSS class in your app with a particular theme, e.g.:

```
.theme1 .myClass {
  color: red;
}

.theme2 .myClass {
  color: blue;
}
```

Then you'll apply a particular theme to the `body` element:

```
<body class="theme1">
```

When you want to change themes, you'll have to change the `body` class so it will become:

```
<body class="theme2">
```

this way, each element that has class `myClass` will have its color changed from red to blue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about it, but here I don't know what will be the different colors. The user will enter for exemple the "button color" : "#000000" and then I will have to color each button ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit a CSS file dynamically, but you can inject CSS style either as a new CSS file, or directly into your document.

For example, you can define all key CSS rules in your "main.css" file, and add your user-defined rules directly into the host HTML page with a `style` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I'm not sure to see what you mean ... how can I add rules into the HTML host page ?

Comment: Using StyleInjector is probably the best option, as Igor suggested.